# ReactJS - React Router not changing component but url is changing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am rookie to ReactJS and recently start learning. I've created 2 components home and ContactList using TSX. I am using React-Router to change route.

**App.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Header } from "./Grid/header";
import { Footer } from "./Grid/footer";
import { Menulink } from './Grid/Menulinks';
import { Home } from './Grid/Home';
import { ContactList } from './Grid/ContactList';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title="This is Header">
        </Header>
        <Menulink></Menulink>
        <Router>
          <switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactList} />
          </switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Menulink.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export class Menulink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <switch>
                    <Link to="/">Home </Link> |
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact List</Link>
                </switch>
            </Router>

        )
    }
}
```

> Issue is, when I click on link, URL change, but component is not
>   getting replace. is it because I've written links and route both in
>   different files?

Comment: Your `switch` looks weird. Import `Switch` from react-router and use that
Also there is no need to wrap `Links` in `Switch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to have one `Router` instance

Second, MenuLink needs to be rendered as a Child of Router

Third, import `Switch` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { Header } from "./Grid/header";
import { Footer } from "./Grid/footer";
import { Menulink } from './Grid/Menulinks';
import { Home } from './Grid/Home';
import { ContactList } from './Grid/ContactList';



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title="This is Header">
        </Header>
        <Router>
          <Route component={Menulink} />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactList} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export class Menulink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <Link to="/">Home </Link> |
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact List</Link>
            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. got the issue. it was silly mistake, but I have just started to learn react. so happening this silly mistakes

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have two different Router instances. You need only One router instance at the Top of the component heirarchy. Or at the very least..the heirarchy that you expect to be changing with URLs.

So if you put your `<MenuLink />` under the `<Router>` that is defining the routes, your routing will work fine.