# React Routing: URL is changing but page is not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In React(v16.13.1), **The URL is changing but page is not loading**.

I found the similar questions [ReactJS - React Router not changing component but url is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568450/reactjs-react-router-not-changing-component-but-url-is-changing)
 and [React Router URL Change but Not Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340595/react-router-url-change-but-not-component) in stack and i tried from different ways but none helps me.

It may be a small mistake, Please help to rectify this.

My code follows:

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Switch,Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./components/Navbar/TopNav";
import SideNav from "./components/Navbar/SideNav";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Analytics from "./components/Analytics";
import ToDo from "./components/ToDo";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TopNav />
        <SideNav />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/analytics">
              <Analytics />
            </Route>
            {/* <Route exact path="/analytics" component={Analytics}></Route> */}
            <Route exact path="/todo">
              <ToDo />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/"></Redirect>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

SideNav.js page as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class SideNav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div className="sidebar-container">
          <Router>
            <ul className="sidebar-menu">
              <li className="active">
                <i className="fa fa-cubes"></i>
                <Link className="link" to="/">
                  Dashboard
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i className="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
                <Link className="link" to="/analytics">
                  Analytics
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i className="fa fa-medkit"></i>
                <Link className="link" to="/todo">
                  What to do?
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SideNav;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try adding the line ```<Route path="/analytics" component={Analytics} />``` (assuming your analytics component name is ```Analytics```)  after the ```ul``` tag and check whether it works for analytics..

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes, with your code. Can you add a snippet to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, Its not working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `<Router>` at top level of your app.

You are already using `<Router>` in your `App` component.

Wrap the `SideNav` component in the `Router` and remove the `Router` used in `SideNav`.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

class SideNav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div className="sidebar-container">
          {/* <Router> */}
          <ul className="sidebar-menu">
            <li className="active">
              <i className="fa fa-cubes" />
              <Link className="link" to="/">
                Dashboard
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i className="fa fa-pie-chart" />
              <Link className="link" to="/analytics">
                Analytics
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i className="fa fa-medkit" />
              <Link className="link" to="/todo">
                What to do?
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {/* </Router> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <SideNav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <div>/</div>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/analytics">
              <div>ana</div>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/todo">
              <div>todo</div>
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<SideNav />` and the main content are in seperate `<Router />`s. They don't see each other, and they can't work together. 
Think, like two iframes navigaing independantly of each other, just without the actual iframes.

Everything that reqiures the router, *basically your entire app*, needs to be inside a single `<Router />`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./components/Navbar/TopNav";
import SideNav from "./components/Navbar/SideNav";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Analytics from "./components/Analytics";
import ToDo from "./components/ToDo";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <TopNav />
        <SideNav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/analytics">
            <Analytics />
          </Route>
          {/* <Route exact path="/analytics" component={Analytics}></Route> */}
          <Route exact path="/todo">
            <ToDo />
          </Route>
          <Redirect to="/"></Redirect>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

SideNav.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class SideNav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div className="sidebar-container">
          <ul className="sidebar-menu">
            <li className="active">
              <i className="fa fa-cubes"></i>
              <Link className="link" to="/">
                Dashboard
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i className="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
              <Link className="link" to="/analytics">
                Analytics
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i className="fa fa-medkit"></i>
              <Link className="link" to="/todo">
                What to do?
                </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The same applies for the `TopNav.js`.